# How do you get a string separated by two new lines based on an index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, newline

Let's say you have string:

```
Apple Banana Pear
Pineapple Grapefruit Kiwi
Lime Lemon Cherry
```

If I wanted the line

```
Pineapple Grapefruit Kiwi
```

how would I get this line from using any index of the second line and finding the newline before the index and the newline after the index?

I've tried doing this:

```
fruits[0].slice(fruits[0].indexOf("\n"),fruits[0]
                       .indexOf("\n", fruits[0].indexOf("\n") + 1))
```

but it doesn't utilize the index but instead it just takes the second line. Sort of like a brute force solution to get the second line.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `split` the string by newlines and select the `[1]`st index - that is, the second line:

```js
const fruits = `Apple Banana Pear
Pineapple Grapefruit Kiwi
Lime Lemon Cherry`;
const [,mid] = fruits.split('\n');
console.log(mid);
```

Or, if you don't want to create an intermediate array, you can `match` the substring that comes after one `\n` and before another `\n`:

```js
const fruits = `Apple Banana Pear
Pineapple Grapefruit Kiwi
Lime Lemon Cherry`;
console.log(fruits.match(/\n([^\n]+)\n/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple solution using `split()` function as follows.

```
function getLineFromString(str, lineNumber) {
      let list = str.split('\n');
      return list[lineNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String fruits = "Apple Banana Pear   
Pineapple Grapefruit Kiwi
Lime Lemon Cherry";
List<String> list = fruits.split("\n");
list.get(1);
```

Now list have all the lines which can be accessed through the index which ever line you want